# Cannot connect to Oracle database server through SQL Developer but Test works OK

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-sql-developer

I am new to Oracle (from a SQL server and MySQL background) and have just installed Oracle 11g2 Express Edition.

I have downloaded SQL developer which appears to be the Oracle world's equivalent to SSMS.
I have gone to the new connection window, given my connection a name, used SYSTEM as the user and my password that I set up at installation. 
I have left hostname/port/sid as default (localhost/1521/xe respectively)

If I click test I get "status: success" However, if I click the connect button, nothing happens.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Check the `listener.ora` file of your local system ans make sure it has TNS entries of your database.

Comment: save the connection. on the tree, expand it - that will attempt a connect. Do you get an error message?

Comment: I believe that if you are connecting as `SYS`, you need to set the `ROLE` to `SYSDBA`.

Answer (score 1):

When you connect from the connection properties dialog, two things will happen in the UI:

[image]

1. the connection icon gets a 'connected' overlay
2. you get a SQL Worksheet***

If your connection is not successful, you'll get an error message, with the text shown at the bottom of the connection properties window.

[image]

***For #2 above, this is conditional on the following preference being enabled, which the default is TRUE.

'Open a Worksheet on connect'